# Properties of the topology with the basis consisting with the sets $A_n = \{n, n+1, \dots \}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $X = \mathbb{N}$ be equiped with the topology generated by the basis consisting of the sets $A_n = \{n, n+1, \dots \}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. **Is $X$ compact? connected? Hausdorff?**

*My Attempt :*

The open sets of $(X, \tau)$ are arbitrary union if the sets of the basis. For any two basis sets $A_j$ and $A_k$, $A_j\cap A_k \neq \phi$. So for any two element $a$ and $b$ we shall not get disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ s.t. $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ s.t. $A\cap B = \phi$. So the topology is not Hausdorff.

To show the compactness we shall show that any open cover of this set should have finite subcover. If we apply well ordering property here we may get finite subcover of any cover of the set $X$. But I am not sure.

This is not path connected trivially. But I am not getting any more for connectedness.

May be this is the first time I am seeing this topology. So please give me some reference for further study about it. **Does this topology or any of its generalization have a nickname?**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a union of basis sets is a basis set itself, so in fact
every open set has form $A_{n}$ for some $n$. If there is an open
cover then there must be some $A_{n}$ with $1\in A_{n}$ and $A_{1}=\mathbb{N}$
 (here $0\notin\mathbb{N}$, but that is not essential) is the only one having that property. Then $\left\{ A_{1}\right\} $
is a finite subcover hence the topological space is compact. It is
connected since an open $A_{n}\neq \mathbb{N}$ always results in a (finite and not empty)  $A_{n}^{c}$ that is not open. As you noticed it is not Hausdorff. I don't know a nickname for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is [the Alexandrov topology on the ordered set $\mathbb N$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology#The_Alexandrov_topology_on_a_preordered_set).

Also note that the induced topology on any two-element subset is that of the Sierpiński space, which is [path-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space#Connectedness).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I did not read your link completely till now. Is it path connected? How?

Comment: @HopelessFool, I have added an explanation for that, but it is much more if you look for a path connecting to points yourself ;)

Comment: Explicitly I am not getting any path between any two elements $(m,n)$. But I understand your second paragraph. If I construct a topological space on $A = \{m,n\}$ as a subspace topology it will be a Sierpinski Space i.e. $\{\phi, \{m\}, \{m,n\}\}$ when $m<n$. Now take mapping $f(x):[0,1] \rightarrow A$ s.t. $f(0) = n$ and $f(x) = m$ when $x > 0$ which is continuous as $(0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$. So in this way we are getting the path between any two points of the topology. Can we write the example more explicitly?