# Properties of this topology on $\mathbb N$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

$\mathbb N$ is consist of the basis generated by the set
 $A_n=\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3....\}$ . 
Then what properties does it have?

- Hausdorff: for any natural numbers $x$ and $y$ there are no disjoint open sets to start with...so I think it's not Hausdorff.
- Connectedness: since all open sets have disjoint intersection so we can't find two disjoint open sets so that union is $\mathbb N$
- Compactness: Any union of sets if it does not contain $A_1$ then it will not be a open cover for $\mathbb N$ but  $A_1 = \mathbb N$ and if I about to take a subcover, I can, by taking  $A_1$ i.e. $\mathbb N$ itself but it doesn't seem right somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properties of the topology with the basis consisting with the sets $A_n = \{n, n+1, \dots \}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629222/properties-of-the-topology-with-the-basis-consisting-with-the-sets-a-n-n-n) (wow, what happened to that formatting?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hausdorff: You're basically correct. However: "there are no disjoint open sets to start with" isn't entirely true. The empty set is disjoint with anything. But since you're required to find two *neighbourhoods*, they can't be empty. If you want to be specific, and $x, y$ are your two points, then any neighbourhood of the smaller of the two points must contain the larger of the two points, and thus have non-empty intersection with any neighbourhood of the larger point.

Connectedness: This is fine, as long as you once again remember to specify "non-empty" open.

Compactness: This is entirely fine. An open cover must contain some neighbourhood of $1$, and there is only one neighbourhood of $1$ and that's $A_1$. But $A_1 = \Bbb N$, so $\{A_1\}$ is a subcover, and it's finite.

Comment: So it is compact right? We can take $\mathbb N$ itself?

Comment: @PranitaGupta $\Bbb N$ itself is the only neighbourhood of $1$, so it must be an element in the covering. So yes. Whether you call it $\Bbb N$ or $A_1$ is entirely up to you.

Comment: In usual topology R is covered by R itself and for any topology X is covered by X itself ... doesn't it makes every topology compact?

Comment: @PranitaGupta No, because with an open cover of, say, $\Bbb R$ in the standard topology, $\Bbb R$ itself doesn't have to be an element in that covering.

Comment: Or maybe when you start to take any cover you don't have to take necessarily R or X like in this case so you won't be having a finite subcover having R or X.

Comment: @PranitaGupta Exactly. This case is special because $1$ only has one open neighbourhood ($\Bbb N$ itself). And since any open covering has to cover $1$, that neighbourhood must be in the covering. For $\Bbb R$, say, we can cover it with the intervals $\{(n-1, n+1)\mid n\in \Bbb Z\}$, and there is no finite subcover.

Comment: Is there any question on properties of a topology with compliment is compact in usually topology on R. Should I ask...?

Answer (score 1):

You're right: the fact that any two non-empty open sets intersect implies both that $\mathbb{N}$ is not Hausdorff and *is* connected (hyperconnected, this is called).
And as the only neighbourhood of $1$ is $A_1=\mathbb{N}$ this set must be in any open cover, making for a one-element subcover. So compact it is.

The definitions tell us, and they are right.

Answer (score 1):

So the main observation here is that **any** open subset in the given topology is actually either $A_n$ or $\emptyset$. That's because $A_n$'s are closed under arbitrary unions and intersections (and this is a consequence of the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered and I leave it as an exercise).

So any two nonempty open subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ have a nonempty intersection. Therefore $\mathbb{N}$ **is not** Hausdorff and **is** connected out-of-the-box.

It is also compact. That's because if $\{A_n\}_{n\in I}$ is a covering then $0$ (or $1$, depending how you count naturals) belongs to some $A_i$. The only choice of such $A_i$ is $A_0$ which is equal to $\mathbb{N}$ and so $\{A_0\}$ is the finite subcover of $\{A_n\}_{n\in I}$.

So this follows because $0$ is special - it is the only element in $\mathbb{N}$ that has only **one** open neighbourhood - namely $\mathbb{N}$ itself. Any topological space with such a special element is compact.